# What is the closest thing to 'date_default_timezone_set' in PHP4?

Tags: php

How can I achieve a similar effect to 'date_default_timezone_set' in PHP4? I need to use the date() function while taking into account local time zones and also day light saving.

Edit: example with putenv:

```
putenv('TZ=Australia/Victoria');    
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

Outputs

> Thursday 6th of October 2011 07:36:49 PM

Actual time here in Victoria

> Friday 7th October 2011 06:36:49 AM

Comment: Not really an answer, but do yourself a favor and upgrade to PHP 5.3. The longer you stick around on v4, the worse the pain will be down the road when you're inevitably forced to upgrade.

Comment: Completely agree. My own servers run PHP5. When working with others, or larger projects it's not as simple as 'just upgrade'. Cheers though

Comment: Who is upvoting this in 2017?? Please do yourself a favour and **don't use PHP4** anymore....

Comment: Who is upvoting this in **2018??** Please do yourself a favour and **don't use PHP4** anymore....

Comment: Who is upvoting this in **2019??** Please do yourself a favour and **don't use PHP4** anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No solution came from this question. I ended up doing a manual work around using the Flash Player.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the TZ environment variable is what you would need to use for this. Using putenv() you should be able to dynamically change the timezone.

Comment: I think that is on the right track, but it appears it doesn't account for day light saving

Comment: That should happen automatically as long as you are using the proper timezone. What specific instance of it not working are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ini_set("date.timezone", "Europe/Berlin"); // PHP 4
```

to sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script!

Instead of using this function to set the default timezone in your script, you can also use the INI setting date.timezone to set the default timezone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." Thus the knowledge base which SO is will really help the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with daylight function:
date("I",time());